# ?attr/actionBarSize in Android 4.4 and higher

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I do not have much Android experience. I'm having issues with my apps when I show them on Android with versions < 5.0. The action bar shows a large space in between the action bar and the rest of the app.

[image: Large space beneath action bar]

But in higher versions, this space is not shown: In this case version 5.0

[image: No extra space beneath action bar]

Is it possible to control such problems from code?

I do not want to generate two different projects for both cases.

Comment: Show your layout file and style of your activity.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in your content xml.
If you used `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`?

Try to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in your `content` view.

Like this:

```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.lxt.app.ui.account.GrowthActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_growth">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

```

Comment: Thanks form your answer, I am going to try it!